# Mysql Query use of AND

Tags: mysql

```
Contest
contest_id  Launched        name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           0               Cont1
2           1               cont2

participants
participants_id       group_id       contest_id      puser_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                     1              1               555
2                     1              1               666

fusers
fuser_id    name
-------------------
555     Alex
666     sabrina
```

I need to write up a query that will select all users(name,groupid,contestname) who are participants of all contests
Details of all users are in `fusers`, where as contest has all contest hosted Launched should be 1 and participants is the table that contains id of users who have decided to participate in a contest.
`fuser_id = puser_id`

Want to find who is participating in contest_id=1 there group_id,contestname and name

Comment: I'd say your description text is too complicated, i can not easily understand...

Comment: Want to find who is participating in contest_id=1 there group_id,contestname and name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not particularly legible, but I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT fusers.fuser_id, fusers.name, Contest.contest_id, Contest.name
FROM fusers
LEFT JOIN participants ON fusers.fuser_id = participants.participants_id
LEFT JOIN Contest ON Contest.contest_id = participants.contest_id
WHERE (Contest.Launched = 1)
```

Comment: hey there, thanks for help
if there is another table invitations and i like to make it like

WHERE (Contest.Launched = 1)
AND participants.puser_id=1 OR participants.puser_id IN (1,2,3) OR (invitations.from=1 and invitations.to IN (6,5,7) )
is it right, i am trying to select all users invited by user id 1

Comment: is there any place where we can post database so as you can see, just like for js there is jsfiddle?

Comment: you would need to add another JOIN condition to add the invitation table and then you could add that criteria to your WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand:

```
SELECT f.name, p.group_id, c.name contestName

FROM
 participants p
 JOIN fusers u on p.puser_id=u.fuser_id
 JOIN contest c on p.contest_id = c.contest_id
WHERE c.launched = 1
 AND c.contest_id = 1 /*or any other contest_id*/
```